# Powershell - Send passive nagios check

Tags: powershell, nagios

How can I send a passive nagios check in a powershell script? In Batch I do:

`<host>\t<svc_description>\t<return_code>\t<plugin_output> | "C:\MyPrograms\send_nsca.exe" -H HOST -C "CONFIG-FILE"`

Comment: I can call this nagios check for now, just need to see, if the pipe thing works as wanted. So far I don't get the check as expected. WOrking on this now. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

`cmd /c 'echo nagios.host   nagios.service  <STATUS-ID> ' $sNagiosTest ' | "C:\Program Files\nsca\send_nsca.exe" -H host_address -c "C:\Program Files\nsca\send_nsca.cfg"'`